# Using nodejs on production server(website) with multiple builds

Tags: php, node.js, apache

I am trying to incorporate NodeJS in our web application.  But I've run into a logistical problem during the planning stages.

Currently, we have a website which serves our web app.  Multiple builds of the web app are served and can be accessed.  For example, you can navigate to oursite.com/builds/532/index.html, oursite.com/builds/534/index.html, oursite.com/builds/latest/index.html.  Now, I know this may not be the best way to go about deploying our application but we are in the middle of making fundamental changes.  But for the time being this is how it is.

Our site is currently using Apache+PHP to serve it.  I'm having trouble coming up with a good deployment process.  If I rewrite the PHP scripts to NodeJS, how will they be served?

Should I use the Forever NodeJS module to create a new process for each build that has been deployed?  That seems clunky and resource heavy as there are more builds.

Or should I write NodeJS to replace Apache tasks, and take in http requests and pipe to the correct build?  This requires writing code that is outside of the build/Git repository.

I'm not sure if I'm describing this well but I'd be happy to clarify and appreciate any help.

EDIT: Additional Info.

We are trying to replace the PHP side of our App with NodeJS for all future builds.  Past builds would still be Apache+PHP.

Comment: You should add some more details. Are you trying to replace the PHP application with node, or just supplement it? What are you doing with all of the legacy builds that they need to all be accessible?

Answer (score 0):

When you write code for Node.js, you are essentially building an application server.  If you want to have multiple versions of code running at the same time, the only way to do this is to run multiple processes.

This isn't a whole lot different than what you have now.  When you load different versions of code currently, PHP fires up and runs that specific version.  The difference is that PHP dies off after it is finished processing a request.

Comment: Is there a way to have NodeJS to execute in response to a request and reset to a cleared state like PHP does, so that each request can be directed to a specific build, and not have that logic cluttered by logic from previous requests?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but then you're losing a lot of what makes node.js worthwhile. What is your motivation for moving to node?